# HP UFT (Unified Functional Testing) : Results View : Is there a way to capture the row, line number of the script where it failed?

Tags: vbscript, report, qtp, hp-uft

[image: Run Results Screen shot]

I usually report the events when it passes or fails like:

```
Reporter.ReportEvent micPass," Title of the passed Event", " Description of Passed Event"
```

And

```
 Reporter.ReportEvent micFail," Title of the failed Event", " Description of Failed Event"
```

Is it a good idea to hard code the line number in the title or description of the event like ?

```
Reporter.ReportEvent micFail," Test Failed at Line 432 ", " Please check line 432 "
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the 2nd part of your question, hard-coding will not be a good idea. If you hard-code the line number and in the future, a few lines get added to the code above that line number, the whole point hard-coding goes in vain as the report will now contain the incorrect-line number(which was hard-coded).

And for the first part, I can understand why you want the line-number to be reported. But I don't think there is any "predefined" way of doing it.

But, you can make your own function to get the line number. Here's an idea that you can implement:

- Go to the location where your QTP test is stored. Get the full path of the file **script.mts**(you can find it inside the Action1 Folder). Also, this path can be constructed dynamically if you have good framework and proper folder structure.
- After getting the path, you can open that file(**script.mts**) as a text stream(using the filesystemobject) in **Read only mode.**
- Now you can traverse through the file line-by-line searching for the text "Reporter.ReportEvent micPass," Title of the passed Event", " Description of Passed Event"". After you have found it, you can easily get the line number and return that from your function to store it in some variable which you can use while reporting.

I have not tried this method myself but would have surely given it a try, If I really needed it.

Comment: The hardcoded part at least gives some hints where the error occurred. I don't have a very good framework I guess. Your idea is good, I just have now to save my script from ALM...

Comment: It might seem like a good idea now. But later when the code is maintained/added/deleted, then you will have to again put efforts to update your hardcoded line numbers everywhere in the script and in all the scripts. Just my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that would seem so, but if they don't match the line number, they can act as an Id with CTRL+F. I'll will study more possibilities. Thank you very much!

Comment: Kira? Do you know a good script to download the script from QC? :)

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding is not a good idea from an  end user perspective. In case it's a  regression suite it could be used by a tester who doesn't know how to debug the code or analyze. To get the root cause of the failure through reporting (micPass/micFail) you can further refine your scripts